# How can I change the maxver parameter of a drive's usn change journal?

Tags: ntfs, fsutil, usn

I have an NTFS hard drive that I need to create a change journal on for my application. However I'm running into errors when attempting to use the created journal and I believe it's due to the maxver parameter that's set on the journal.

When I run `fsutil usn queryjournal C:` the output is as follows

```
Usn Journal ID   : 0x01d50d43f54b5ab8
First Usn        : 0x0000000094800000
Next Usn         : 0x0000000096fc6828
Lowest Valid Usn : 0x0000000000000000
Max Usn          : 0x7fffffffffff0000
Maximum Size     : 0x0000000002000000
Allocation Delta : 0x0000000000800000
Minimum record version supported : 2
Maximum record version supported : 2
Write range tracking: Disabled
```

Notice the "Maximum record version supported :2" line. The issue is that my application depends on the [USN_RECORD_V3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ns-winioctl-usn_record_v3)

On a different drive on a different machine, where my application runs correctly, the maxver parameter is set to 4.

I've tried running `fsutil usn createjournal maxver=4 C:` to update the maxver, but even though the command executes, the version number doesn't update. I've also tried creating a new journal altogether with this command to no avail (max record version still reads as 2).

How is this maxver parameter determined? How can I change the maxver of a given drive? Any insight around this would be great.